# How to disable "No target found for method X" exception

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I have a style in my xaml-resources. It looks like this:

```
<Border cm:Message.Attach="[Event Tapped] = [Action UserCardTapped($dataContext)]">
 ...
</Border>
```

So I use this style in the different pages and different viewModels, but not all viewModels need to implement a method `UserCardTapped`. And here is the problem - if my viewModel doesn't contain a `UserCardTapped` method, Caliburn throws an exception with a message "No target found for method UserCardTapped".

Is it possible to disable binding to the method if it doesn't exist?

---

Why down-voting? Is there more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionMessage.ThrowsExceptions = false;` will do the trick.